# Robocopy as another user

Tags: powershell, robocopy

**Problem:** Robocopy not launching as another user in `Start-Process`

The script works fine when running on an account that has the permissions for both file locations but it just doesnt seem to be accepting the `-credential` param.

Unsure if my formatting is incorrect or if I am doing something wrong.

```
# Create Password for credential
$passw = convertto-securestring "Password" -asplaintext –force
# Assembles password into a credential
$creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "DOMAIN\Username", $passw
# Select a source / destination path, can contain spaces
$Source = '\\Source\E$\Location'
$Destination = '\\Destination\Location Here'
# formats the arguments to allow the credentials to be wrapped into the command
$RoboArgs = "`"$($Source)`" `"$($Destination)`"" + " /e /Copy:DAT"
# Started Robocopy with arguments and credentials
Start-Process -credential $creds Robocopy.exe -ArgumentList $RoboArgs -Wait
```

Comment: check if you are trying to execute it from an admin account and it doesnt have access to the source drives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Robocopy will use the standard windows authentication mechanism.

So you probably need to connect to the servers using the appropriate credentials before you issue the robocopy command.

You can use `net use` to do this.

```
net use X: '\\Source\E$\Location' /user:MYDOMAIN\USER THEPASSWORD
net use Y: '\\Destination\Location Here' /user:MYDOMAIN\USER THEPASSWORD

net use X: /d
net use Y: /d
```

and then start your `ROBOCOPY`

Answer (score 2):

S.Spieker's answer will work, but if you want to use PowerShell built in command and pass the credentials as a pscredential object you could use New-PSDrive to mount the drives:

```
    $passw = convertto-securestring "Password" -asplaintext –force
    $creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "DOMAIN\Username", $passw
    $SourceFolder = '\\Source\E$\Location'
    $DestinationFolder = '\\Destination\Location Here'

    New-PSDrive -Name MountedSource -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $SourceFolder -Credential $creds
    New-PSDrive -Name MountedDestination -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $DestinationFolder -Credentials $creds

    Robocopy.exe \\MountedSource \\MountedDestination /e /Copy:DAT"

    Remove-PSDrive -Name MountedSource 
    Remove-PSDrive -Name MountedDestination
```

* I might have the Robocopy wrong, it's been years since I used it, but the mounting drives is correct.